# angular 2 - npm error

Tags: npm, angular

I was following [5 Min Quickstart - js - Angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) guide and get a strange error after calling "npm start":

```
> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start C:\Users\stavalfi\Desktop\plunkerExample
> npm run lite


> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite C:\Users\stavalfi\Desktop\plunkerExample
> lite-server

'lite-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js
" "run" "lite"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     lite-server
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\stavalfi\Desktop\plunkerExample\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js
" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `npm run lite`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'npm run lite'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run lite
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\stavalfi\Desktop\plunkerExample\npm-debug.log
```

**Update: While installing "npm install lite-server -g", I get those errors:**

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 
SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed else
where.  [C:\Users\stavalfi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lite-server\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_m
odules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269
:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\stavalfi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lite-server\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\nod
e_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\stavalfi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lite-server\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules
\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code `ENOENT` means "no such file or directory".

You should check of you have the file `C:\Users\stavalfi\package.json` present and accessible by the application... Do you execute the command in the right folder?

Comment: The package wasnt located in the right location. But now I get new errors. Any additional help will be blessed!

Comment: I would say that your lite server isn't installed globally. Try with the `-g` option: npm install lite-server -g

Comment: Did that and got some strange errors. I do have VS 2015 and I think it comes with C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update npm? I had some other problems with the 5 minute quick start, but after I updated npm I could run npm start without any errors.